# webpack 4: Bundle css files to one main.css (and a main.min.css)

Tags: css, webpack

I've got a structure like this:

```
src/
-- styles/
   -- a.css
-- scripts/
   -- b.js
   -- c.js
```

and im looking to produce a dist like:

```
dist/
-- main.js
-- main.min.js
-- main.css
-- main.min.css
```

I've successfully done the js part, but cant figure out how to do it with css. Most of the techniques i see bundle the css into the js, but i need to distribute the css separately for my use case. Thanks!

**edit:
I figured it out, i needed to require them in the main.js entry file, i guess they get extracted out from there**

heres my current config-

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "main": './source/scripts/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
            include: /\.min\.js$/
        })]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            // you can specify a publicPath here
                            // by default it use publicPath in webpackOptions.output
                            publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
                        }
                    },
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: do you have any initial webpack config that handles css?

Comment: @PlayMa256 updated